# arrange the result into multiple table based on a column in servlet before submitting to db

Tags: java, servlets

I would like to split generated data from db into several tables in servlet and DISPLAY IT. The table is organized using presentation ID. For example, I have 10 people. I need to assign supervisor and examiner with the same `availableID`. My system will identify if they have similar `availableID`.

I would like to display it using servlet TEMPORARILY before the admin click on SAVE button and insert it into db.

Sevlet:

```
            for (int i=0; i<studentID.length ; i++) {
            FreeBean free = new FreeBean();
            free = GenerateScheduleDAO.getFree(supervisorID[i],examinerID[i]);

            String SVavailableID = free.getAvailableID();
            String EXavailableID = free.getAvailableID();
            Date FreeDate = free.getFreeDate();

            System.out.println("sv: "+ supervisorID[i] + SVavailableID + " ev: "+ examinerID[i] + EXavailableID);

            if (SVavailableID.equals(EXavailableID))
            {
                if(SVavailableID.equals("2")&& EXavailableID.equals("2")){
                     out.println("<br><center><table><tr>"
                                    + "<th>Name</th>"
                                    + "<th>Title</th>"
                                    + "<th>Supervisor</th>"
                                    + "<th>Examiner Name</th>"
                                    + "<th>availableID</th>"
                                    + "<th>Time </th>"
                                    + "</tr>");
                    out.println("<tr>");

                    out.println("<tr>");
                    out.println("<td>"+ studentID[i]+"</td>");
                    out.println("<td> Hello </td>");
                    out.println("<td>"+ supervisorID[i] +"</td>");
                    out.println("<td>"+ examinerID[i] +"</td>");
                    out.println("<td>"+ SVavailableID+"</td>");
                    out.println("<td>"+ FreeDate+"</td>");
                    out.println("</tr><br>");
                    out.println("</center></table>");
                }//2
                 if(SVavailableID.equals("7")&& EXavailableID.equals("7")){
                     out.println("<br><center><table><tr>"
                                    + "<th>Name</th>"
                                    + "<th>Title</th>"
                                    + "<th>Supervisor</th>"
                                    + "<th>Examiner</th>"
                                    + "<th>availableID </th>"
                                    + "<th>Time</th>"
                                    + "</tr>");
                    out.println("<tr>");

                    out.println("<tr>");
                    out.println("<td>"+ studentID[i]+"</td>");
                    out.println("<td> Hello </td>");
                    out.println("<td>"+ supervisorID[i] +"</td>");
                    out.println("<td>"+ SVavailableID+"</td>");
                    out.println("<td>"+ FreeDate+"</td>");
                    out.println("</tr><br>");
                    out.println("</center></table>");
                }//7
                  if(SVavailableID.equals("10")&& EXavailableID.equals("10")){
                     out.println("<br><center><table><tr>"
                                    + "<th> Name</th>"
                                    + "<th> Title</th>"
                                    + "<th>Supervisor</th>"
                                    + "<th>Examiner</th>"
                                    + "<th>availableID </th>"
                                    + "<th>Time </th>"
                                    + "</tr>");
                    out.println("<tr>");

                    out.println("<tr>");
                    out.println("<td>"+ studentID[i]+"</td>");
                    out.println("<td> Hello </td>");
                    out.println("<td>"+ supervisorID[i] +"</td>");
                    out.println("<td>"+ examinerID[i] +"</td>");
                    out.println("<td>"+ SVavailableID+"</td>");
                    out.println("<td>"+ FreeDate+"</td>");
                    out.println("</tr><br>");
                    out.println("</center></table>");
                }
                   if(SVavailableID.equals("16")&& EXavailableID.equals("16")){
                     out.println("<br><center><table><tr>"
                                    + "<th>Name</th>"
                                    + "<th>Title</th>"
                                    + "<th>Supervisor</th>"
                                    + "<th>Examiner</th>"
                                    + "<th>availableID </th>"
                                    + "<th>Time </th>"
                                    + "</tr>");
                    out.println("<tr>");

                    out.println("<tr>");
                    out.println("<td>"+ studentID[i]+"</td>");
                    out.println("<td> Hello </td>");
                    out.println("<td>"+ supervisorID[i] +"</td>");
                    out.println("<td>"+ examinerID[i] +"</td>");
                    out.println("<td>"+ SVavailableID+"</td>");
                    out.println("<td>"+ FreeDate+"</td>");
                    out.println("</tr><br>");
                    out.println("</center></table>");
                }

            }
```

However, I am getting this result :

```
    Name        Title   Supervisor  Examiner availableID     Time
    abc         Hello     1024       1001           7        null
    Name        Title   Supervisor  Examiner availableID     Time
    abc         Hello     1024       1001           7        null
    Name        Title   Supervisor  Examiner availableID     Time
    abc         Hello     1024       1001           7        null
    Name        Title   Supervisor  Examiner availableID     Time
    abc         Hello     1024       1001           7        null (so on..)
```

Expected outcome will be:

Table `availableID = 7`:

```
Name        Title   Supervisor  Examiner availableID     Time
abc         Hello     1024       1001           7        null
def         Hi        1024       1001           7        null
ghi         Hey       1002       1004           7        null
jkl         hhh       1027       1011           7        null
mno         123       1014       1034           7        null
```

Table `availableID = 10`:

```
    Name        Title   Supervisor  Examiner availableID    Time
    pqr         3333      1026       1021           10      null
    stu         4444      1023       1001           10      null
    vwx         5555      1002       1002           10      null
    yz1         6666      1027       1031           10      null
    234         7777      1034       1004           10      null
```

How can I sort this things out?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I would like to split the result based on `availableID`. Look at my expected outcome. But my codes, produce the last  outcome.

Answer (score 0):

First off it looks like you are repeating code over and over. Regardless of what ID you get, you are performing the same exact (or similar) tasks.
I would suggest grouping together the conditions that can be grouped together and write a single block of code, where possible.

So it would be something like this

```
if (SVavailableID.equals(EXavailableID)){
    if (SVavailableID.equals("7") || SVavailableID.equals("2") || // and so on...) {
        // print students data
   }
}
```

Secondly I would intuitively say that you don't want to print ***table headers*** for each student.
You want to print them beforehand and then loop through the `array` of students to print out their details. So the following fragment of code would go outside your `for loop`

```
// outside the for loop
out.println("<br><center><table><tr>"
    + "<th>Name</th>"
    + "<th>Title</th>"
    + "<th>Supervisor</th>"
    + "<th>Examiner</th>"
    + "<th>availableID </th>"
    + "<th>Time</th>"
    + "</tr>");

// now loop through students array and print details here...
```

Lastly based on your output, since you keep getting the same values, I would think that something is wrong with one of the following:

1. the data you are looping through
2. the fact that you are looping through a `studentID` array but it doesn't seem like you are looping through a data structure containing the data to be displayed on the table (if you could clarify what `free` represents that would help)
3. the following statements inside your `for loop`.

   ```
   // most likely they'll have the same value!!
   String SVavailableID = free.getAvailableID();
   String EXavailableID = free.getAvailableID();
   ```

Before printing `html` you are comparing their values, but those statements are assigning the same value to those ID'S; it's unlikely that they'll return different results, unless you have implemented some sort of logic withing the `getAvailableID()` method that makes it possible.

EDIT : I just read your comment on your answer where you explained how you want to have separate tables for each available ID

I'll try and sketch a pseudocode algorithm to do that

```
// loop through each available ID 
for(String ID : availableIdCollection){

    // print table headers here

    // loop through students array
    for(Student s : studentCollection){

        // print students data here
    }
}
```

You would basically have two nested for loops.

1. In the outer loop you'd loop through the available ID'S
2. before the inner loop you would print the table headers
3. After printing the table headers you would want to loop through the student array and print each student data

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will look through it and Ill let you know later :) @AngeloOparah